# Which way is faster to copy the data from a matrix to other matrix in C/C++?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have two matrix which are A1 and A. The matrix A1 has data. I want to copy (two cases):

1. All data from A1 to A
2. Copy selected row from A1 to A

I have two way to copy A1 to A for each case. It is that I will copy each element from A1 to A. Or, I will copy by using memcpy. Which way is more faster in C/C++. Could you see the way which uses memcpy and let me know if it was wrong? Thanks

```
***********************************************************************************/
    typedef unsigned char  U8;
    typedef unsigned int   U32;
    U8** A1;
    U8** A;
    //Alloc A1 and A matries
    int M1=32;
    int N1=64;
    int M=64;
    int N=128;
    A1= new U8*[M1]; //Max number of rows that M can achieve 
    for (U32 i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
    {
      A1[i] = new U8[N1];
      memset(A1[i],0,N1);
    }
    A= new U8*[M]; //Max number of rows that M can achieve 
    for (U32 i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      A[i] = new U8[N];
      memset(A[i],0,N);
    }

    // Assume A1 is set data in here
    // Now we will copy A1 to A
    // Use first way- copy element by element
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
      for(U32 j=0; j<N;j++)
          A[i] = A1[i];
    }
    //Use second way is memset
    for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
         memcpy(A[i],A1[i],N);
    }
```

Comment: This is not c++, it's c

Comment: memset is wrong function. Use memcpy to copy values from one array to another.

Comment: @user8430  The code has undefined behaviour. It is entirely invalid.:)

Comment: No, the code is wrong - use std:vector!!!

Comment: Sorry. I cannot use vector in here. Because if it use it, the design must be change. I reference a original design which use matrix

Comment: If it's C... Why are you using `new`?

Comment: I update it. I am using C++ for above code

Comment: There are so many mistakes here, you almost certainly need to throw all the code away and properly learn the basics. Stop worrying about speed when you patently can't write code that is correct.

Comment: Could you figure out my error? I used the first way and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: memset's third argument is number of bytes, that should be set by value of second argument. Use `NumberOfElements * sizeof(TypeOfElements)`:

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < N1; ++i)
{
  A1[i] = new U8[N1];
  memset(A1[i],0,N1 * sizeof(U8));
}
A= new U8*[M]; //Max number of rows that M can achieve 
for (U32 i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
  A[i] = new U8[N];
  memset(A[i],0,N * sizeof(U8));
}
```

Second: you con't run your loops to `M` and `N` because in `A1` memory was allocated only to `M1` and `N1` which is less than `M` and `N` in current context. Also you forgot second index then you matrix copying by elements.

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i)
{
  for(U32 j=0; j<N1;j++)
      A[i][j] = A1[i][j];
}
//Use second way is memset
for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i)
{
     memcpy(A[i],A1[i],N1 * sizeof(U8));
}
```

P.S. Don't forget about free memory after you allocate it.
Add somthing like

```
void destroy(U8 **matrix, int rowCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete []matrix;
}
```

and call this function after all work with matrix was down.

Edit:
In loops which copying values via memcpy I change indices from `M` and `N` to `M1` and `N1`. Previous where incorrect.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly what I need. I just ask small issue. That is I want to copy A1 to A but A1 is located in right side, botton of A. How can I use the memcpy? For example,    U32 shift_location=32
   for (U32 i = 0; i < M1; ++i)
   {
     for (U32 j = 0; j < N1; ++j)
     {
       A[i+shift_location][j+shift_location]=A1[i][j];
     }
   }

Comment: You can simply add this shift to destination pointer: `memcpy(A[i] + shift_location, A1[i], N1 * sizeof(U8));`

Comment: This will shift values in one dimension. Such arifmetic is correct for pointers. No additional `* sizeof(PutTypeHere)`. For shift in other dimension `A[i + shift_location]`. Indexer operator will give correct row array. So, if we combine two shifts we obain `A[i + shift_location] + shift_location` for destination buffer.

Comment: Thank Semyon Burov for your help..I just ask one more thing about free matrix. Do you need check if(matrix) before free it? I am using this code to free     if (A)
    {
      for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
      {
 delete [] A[i];
      }
    }
    delete[] A;
    A= NULL; Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, this will work. I think, checking `A` for NULL is redundant, but better ask someone other.

Answer (score 1):

You can allocate and copy the memory for the matrix data at once:

```
U8** A;
A = new U8*[M];      // allocate memory for pointer to rows
A[0] = new U8 [M*N]; // allocate memory for matrix data
for (int i = 1; i < M; i++)
    A[i] = A[i-1]+N    // assigne to each row its memory
memset(A[0], 0, M*N*sizeof(U8));

// copy matrix data
memcopy(A1[0], A[0], M*N*sizeof(U8));
```